# How to prevent users from editing electron source files?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

I'm working on a project that also has a premium version and it is built of Electron. For the sake of simplicity let's suppose that there is a function called `check_if_premium()` where it will send a GET request with the user's token to the server and check if they have premium.

I noticed that when you build the Electron project, all the source is fully editable and visible. Does this mean that a user could just go edit the javascript file to simply `return true` always? If so, what can be done to make this more difficult/impossible to do?

Comment: in dist folder it will be executable file. you have to use only that. so from .exe file no one will get source code.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra in the same folder as the project.exe there is the `resources` folder which contains all the source. If you delete that folder the .exe doesn't work anymore.

Comment: .exe should work independent, may be you are generating .exe in some other way.

Comment: How can I generate it so that it works independently? I'm just using `npm run make` to build the project.

Comment: i am using electron-builder `https://www.electron.build/`, it will also useful for auto-update your app